# How to get records with a where condition is a string array

Tags: c#, linq

In the code below, `profile` is a string. I would like to know how to write a query in case where `profile` is a string array or list. ie the array or list can have multiple elements like { 'Profile1','profile2'}

```
var ccData = (from p in db.ChannelContacts where p.ProfileId == profile select p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an efficient join:

```
var ccData = from p in db.ChannelContacts 
             join profileID in profiles // your collection
             on p.ProfileId equals profileID
             select p;
```

another less efficient option is `Contains`:

```
var ccData = from p in db.ChannelContacts 
             where profiles.Contains(p.ProfileId)
             select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply ask, if `profile` contains that `ProfileId`

```
var ccData = (from p in db.ChannelContacts 
              where profile.Any(prof => prof == p.ProfileId) 
              select p);
```